# What is a word for the paragraphs of text on a college website advertising or sharing stories about the school in a positive light?

Tags: single-word-requests

Pretty self explanatory - a word to describe this kind of positive, well-composed text.

Comment: What sort of descriptive word do you want, a noun or an adjective? Can you give an example sentence showing the context where you will use this word?

Comment: It's not self-explanatory to those of us who don't look at college websites and have not seen what you're asking about. Please link to one or more such sites to give some examples.

Comment: In a general sense, "promotional" comes to mind.

Comment: *Testimonials*?

Comment: *Propaganda*?  :D

Comment: In my shop such texts are called *blurbs* or *fluff*.

Comment: public relations! Don

Comment: any link of a website?

Comment: "Hype" is one word.

Comment: The text in any advertising medium can be called "copy" or "content"

Answer (score 1):

This is a **blurb**:

> A brief publicity notice, as on a book jacket. [[American Heritage Dictionary]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blurb)

The term is indeed strongly associated with book jackets, but not absolutely exclusively.

Comment: My all-time favorite book-jacket blurb is by Dylan Thomas, for Flann O'Brien's *At Swim-Two-Birds:* "This is just the book to give your sister--if she's a loud, dirty, boozy girl."